# Increase playback speed of video in PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, video

I'm using PowerPoint 2016. In my presentations I can include mp4 videos but I would also like to increase the speed of the playback (e.g. 16 times faster). How can this be done? I did not find any possibility to do this.

Comment: remake teh video at 16 times the speed?

Comment: @joojaa Remaking the video is not a possibility because it takes a long time to process it.

Comment: You do understand that you would have done it by now?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change the playback speed of a video in powerpoint, which i discovered after following [this tip](http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00712_Playing_movies_in_slow_or_fast_motion.htm). Here are the steps required:

1. Enable the 'Developer' Tab in the ribbon, found under Powerpoint options > Customize Ribbon > Main Tabs.
2. In the Developer Tab in the ribbon, in the 'Controls' section, access the 'more controls' option.
3. In the More Controls popup, scroll to the bottom of the list and select 'Windows Media Player'
4. Click anywhere on your slide to create a new windows media player instance. *Note: this may raise a security warning as you are activating an ActiveX control. You must enable to continue.*
5. Right click on the windows media player and select 'Properties' or 'Property Sheet'
6. Click the three dots icon next to 'Custom' to launch a dialog, where you can initiate file selection or manually enter a url (alternatively, you can enter the file path or URL directly into the URL property). *Note: your file or url must be a windows media playable file*.
7. At the 'Custom' property, click to open windows media player options window.
8. Click the 'advanced' tab, and alter the figure in the 'Rate' field.

Voila!

The normal / default playback rate is 1.0000. Change this figure to .5000 to play the video at half speed (i.e. slower), or change it to 2.0000 for double-speed playback (i.e. faster).

Answer (score 1):

Ha!

I found another way after trawling ALL day for answers. However, I'm using PwrPt 2013, so maybe it will work for you and maybe it won't.

- Open Windows Movie Maker.
- Add your video file to it.
- Under the Edit tab, set your preferred speed from dropdown menu.
- Under Home tab>> Save Movie dropdown menu>> For Computer/High Definition (whichever you prefer. Without doing this, your file won't be compatible with PwrPt)>> choose folder location and file name>> save.

The video will be converted into a suitable file format while saving the preferred speed and you can insert it into Powerpoint.

Apparently, this also works for VLC player, but haven't used it myself.

Answer (score 1):

"More Controls" has no popup and no items such as 'Windows Media Player'.

So perhaps the above post by christianhanvey is for an older version
and not for Office 365 Powerpoint ?

I determined a solution

1. by uploading the separate videos to the free website:
   https://online-video-cutter.com/change-video-speed
   (note: This website does not put their Water Mark on
   your videos)
2. and I then slowed down and sped up the videos and saved them
3. Next I uploaded the adjusted videos to my Powerpoint

Comment: @christianhanvey's answer works for me (using the latest Office 365 as of Oct 2023), but I wanted to have the file embedded in the Powerpoint file, so I used your solution instead.